# Invalid index in cross-module reference

Tags: system-verilog

below is the code snippet of my top_file

```
`define NUM_SENSORS 2;

module test_top();

  svt_configuration multiple_top_cfg[`NUM_SENSORS]; // configuration class instance

  svt_xmtr_if xmtr_if[`NUM_OF_SENSORS]();  // interface instance
  svt_rcvr_if rcvr_if[`NUM_OF_SENSORS](); 

  always begin
    fork
      change_clock_speed();
    join_none
  end

  task automatic change_clock_speed();

    for(i=0; i<`NUM_OF_SENSORS; i++) begin
      wait(multiple_top_cfg[i] != null);
      @(multiple_new_dphy_ui[i]) begin 
        if(multiple_top_cfg[i].xmtr_cfg.lane_cfg.clock_type == svt_mipi_lane_configuration::NON_CONTINUOUS) begin
          wait({xmtr_if[i].serial_if.serial_tx_clk_if.dp,xmtr_if[i].serial_if.serial_tx_clk_if.dn} === 2'b11);
        end
        else begin
          if(multiple_top_cfg[i].xmtr_cfg.lane_cfg.clock_type == svt_mipi_lane_configuration::CONTINUOUS) begin
            wait({xmtr_if[i].serial_if.serial_if[0].dp,xmtr_if[i].serial_if.serial_if[0].dn} === 2'b11);
          end
        end
        multiple_change_dphy_ui[i] = 1;   //  this is a local reg
        multiple_tx_clock_period[i] = multiple_new_dphy_ui[i]; // this is a local reg
        multiple_quadrature[i] = multiple_new_dphy_ui[i];  // this is a local reg
      end
    end

  endtask
  // ... other lines
endmodule
```

When i am running my test, i am getting this error :

`Error-[IIXMR] Invalid index in cross-module reference
top.serial.sv, 311
  Invalid index in cross-module reference due to index is not constant.
  Argument: xmtr_if[i].serial_if.serial_tx_clk_if.dp
  Source info: : wait (({xmtr_if[i].serial_if.serial_tx_clk_if.dp,
  xmtr_if[i].serial_if.serial_tx_clk_if.dn} === 2'b11))`

I understand why this error is coming, but i don't have any solution to it... can any one help...

I tried to put the always block inside `generate` block. But another error is coming. 
Any solution to this error please...

Thanks,
Biren

Comment: Can you post the code that contains the generate blocks? I mean the definition of xmtr_if[i].serial_if.serial_tx_clk_if.dp

Comment: This can possible happen if xmtr_if[i].serial_if.serial_tx_clk_if.dp is inside an unnamed generate block

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution it. What i did is :

```
genvar i;
generate
  for(i=0; i<`NUM_SENSORS; i++) begin
    always begin
      change_clock_speed();
    end
  end
endgenerate
```

Now it's working. :)